# Can't SSH to Google Cloud Compute Engine with sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh, google-compute-engine

I prepared two VM instance with Compute Engine on GCP.
ServerA: Data processing and read/write to SQL(mysql) on ServerB.
ServerB: SQL Server (f1-micro* This is not Cloud SQL, but normal VM instance.)

Trying to access SSH from A to B in order to read/write DB on ServerB with the code below.

error code

> error: ERROR   | Problem setting SSH Forwarder up: Couldn't open tunnel localhost:3306 <> localhost:3306 might be in use or destination not reachable
>
> sshtunnel.HandlerSSHTunnelForwarderError: An error occurred while opening tunnels.

```
#SSH connection
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('PublicIP of ServerA', 22),
    ssh_pkey=SSH_PKEY_PATH,
    ssh_username=SSH_USER,
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)
) as ssh:
    try:
    #DB connection
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='localhost',
                port = 3306,
                user=MYSQL_USER,
                passwd=MYSQL_PASS,
                db=MYSQL_DB,
                charset='utf8'
            )
    # print(connection.is_connected())
    # Get Cur
        cur = connection.cursor()
        sql = "use dbname"
        cur.execute(sql)
        
        for i in range(len(sqlList)):
            print("DB Access：" + str(sqlList[i]))
            sql = str(sqlList[i])
        # sql = 'create table test (id int, content varchar(32))'
            cur.execute(sql)
            sqlOUTPUT = cur.fetchall()
    # rows = cur.fetchall()
    # for row in rows:
    #     print(row)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
        connection.rollback()
        raise err
    finally:
        #Cur close
        cur.close()
        # Commit
        connection.commit()
        #DB Connection close
        connection.close()
return sqlOUTPUT
```

But after "local_bind_address=(localhost, MYSQL_PORT)", an error occurs despite it goes through with the same code and same private key on the shell of B or on VSCode local environment.

I don't understand why it goes through with same code using shell and VSCode although it doesn't work on GCE.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to debug this further and discard any issues with [sshtunnel](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/) if you try to create the tunnel outside of the script from the client VM, with:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh server-a --zone=your-zone --ssh-flag='-NL 3306:127.0.0.1:3306' &
```

Then attempt a connection with:

```
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1
```